# error parsing XML file to google maps (XML Parsing Error: junk after document element)

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I have a problem with my XML file that loads the google maps markers. The map works with some postal codes but doesn't work with others.

These are the xml files. This first one works fine. The second one doesn't. It gives an "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element" error.

1. www.soshapal.com/maptst.php?lat=45.5001031&lng=-73.57686610000002&radius=5km&country_id=2&city_id=30&section_id=2
2. www.soshapal.com/maptst.php?lat=45.4932559&lng=-73.57964709999999&radius=5km&country_id=2&city_id=30&section_id=2

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML creation script is attempting to inform you of errors:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMElement::setAttribute() [<a href='domelement.setattribute'>domelement.setattribute</a>]: string is not in UTF-8 in <b>/home/vozemg0/public_html/soshapal.com/maptst.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMElement::setAttribute() [<a href='domelement.setattribute'>domelement.setattribute</a>]: string is not in UTF-8 in <b>/home/vozemg0/public_html/soshapal.com/maptst.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::saveXML() [<a href='domdocument.savexml'>domdocument.savexml</a>]: output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xE9 0x61 0x6C 0x2C in <b>/home/vozemg0/public_html/soshapal.com/maptst.php</b> on line <b>64</b><br />
```

Those messages are making the XML invalid.

Comment: it seems that i had some french letters in some of the addresses.everything is fixed  when i changed it.thanks alot for the help